# Force window to scroll on when loaded

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() + 1);
   $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() - 1);
});
```

I want to use this code to force the window to scroll down and up one pixel when loaded. This to cause events using a scroll function to activate. But nothing seems to happen. All other code I have is triple checked and working independently.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you really expect to notice an instantaneous _single pixel_ scroll down then immediately up again?

Comment: did you try a delay between the 2 statements?

Comment: Seems like a hacky workaround anyway for whatever real problem you were facing. Why can't you make that other code trigger on load as well as on scroll?

Comment: I am using $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() + 1);
$(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() - 1); else where and then it works fine, but not in the above configuration with $(document).ready(function() { ,I am not expecting to see the scroll occur, just to trigger other events with the scroll.

Comment: Haven't tried a delay between the two statements. How do I go about that?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do:

```
$(window).trigger("scroll")
```

Or if other things are listening for their own scroll event, select everything even:

```
$("*").trigger("scroll")
```

Comment: Woah, why trigger a scroll event on each and every element?

Comment: Sometimes a specific element listens for it's own scroll event, not the window event, but most likely only need to do the window.